# Graph Clustering

Tags: graph, social-networking

I've been searching paper about method review in graph clustering but not satisfied me, 
please tell me what is best method *(according to you)* in graph clustering, so sorry if my question very general

Thanks

Comment: This is indeed a very general question. Also, there is no such thing as **the best method** in cluster analysis. There is [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) [useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) for clustering, but probably only one will give you the results you want. Speaking of the results, maybe you can refine your question, and tell us a little more about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such an open question, I guess I can recommend you to try [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/).

It has a nice set of user interfaces to let you import your dataset and then try and compare various classification and clustering algorithms on your data, without writing even one line of code.

After you identified an algorithm that works for your problem, you can then search for a nice and fast implementation in the programming language of your choice.

EDIT: since you mentioned the `graph` tag, maybe you should have a look at [Markov Cluster Algorithm](http://www.micans.org/mcl/), or else, you will have a hard time trying to represent your graph data in a format suitable for the *distance* based clustering algorithms in WEKA.